# Error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw(<unresolved overloaded function type>)' SFML C++

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, sfml, virtual-functions

I tried to create a Button class and use it with SFML, unfortunately, I get the error:

```
E:\...\something.cpp:154:40: error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
                 sfmlWin.draw(buttt.Butt);
                                        ^
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

void onclic(){cout << "Clicked";}

class Button{
public:
    string ButtonText;
    Color color;
    int sizee;
    int x;
    int y;
    RenderWindow winname;
    void func(){cout << "Something";}

    void Butt(string ButtonText, Color color, int sizee, int x, int y, function<void()> funcc, RenderWindow& winname){

        Text tt;
        tt.setString(ButtonText);
        tt.setColor(color);
        tt.setPosition(x, y);
        tt.setCharacterSize(sizee);
        Event e;
        while (winname.pollEvent(e)) {

            switch (e.type) {
        case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
            funcc();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow sfmlWin;
    sfmlWin.setTitle("Hello!");
    sf::Font font;
    while (sfmlWin.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event e;
        while (sfmlWin.pollEvent(e)) {
            switch (e.type) {
            case sf::Event::EventType::Closed:

                Text t;
                t.setString("Something");
                sfmlWin.draw(t);
                Button buttt;
                Color col(0,255,0);
                buttt.Butt("CLICK!", col, 20, 50, 50, onclic, sfmlWin);
                sfmlWin.draw(buttt.Butt);
            }
        }
        sfmlWin.clear();
        sfmlWin.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

If a Button class cannot be achieved in this way, is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Drawable.php    if you want Button to be drawable object, inherit from `sf::Drawable`, and put all drawing methods into overridden `draw` method. `Button btn; sfmlWin.draw(btn);`

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Button` must be derived from `sf::Drawable` and in there you override the draw method:

```
class Button : public sf::Drawable
{
protected:
    void draw (RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const override
    {
        // your draw implementation, which is called Butt() I think
    }
}
```

Then you pass it in your main like this:

```
Button button;
sfmlWin.draw(button);
```

Comment: Very sorry for the late reply. I have been getting this error: `cannot declare variable 'buttt' to be of abstract type 'Button'|`. When I remove `virtual` from virtual void in the `protected:`, and add `override` with `const` at the end; I get this error: `error: 'void Button::draw(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates, std::__cxx11::string, sf::Color, int, int, int, std::function<void()>, sf::RenderWindow&) const' marked 'override', but does not override|`. Do these have to do with other parts of the code? What mistake am I making? I have added `: public sf::Drawable` after `class Button` also.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I think you should ask this in another question. For me it looks like that you don't understand the concepts of inheritance in c++

Comment: Oh, yes. Sure..